# Axios ajax call does not work

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to fire an ajax call when I click the a href tag:

```
<a v-bind:href="row.href" @click.prevent="ajaxCall(row.href)" title="Click for more info">
    {{ row.label }}
</a>
```

Which fires this simple ajax call;

```
ajaxCall(param){
    axios.get("/"+param).then(({data})=>{
    this.rows = data.rows;
});
```

The thing is that I update the href from backend each time the user clicks the link, when clicking two times over the a href it works it fires the ajax call I get the data, but when clicking third time it does not work.

[image]

Also a href its correct except that for some reason on third click axios does not include base url

I noticed that the url its wrong also the content type its not json which it should. Any suggestion?

Comment: If the code works for a few requests then it just works. It should be because of your response, which is something we cannot see here ;)